# A circled inequality relation symbol similar to the circled arithmetic operators

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a variation on the `\odot` (a circled dot) and `\oplus` (a circled plus) operators, but for the inequality relations. In other words, I'm looking for the symbol to substitute for the blank in the second printed line of following example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
c\cdot x + y &\leq z\\
c\odot x\oplus y &\quad\ z
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: A missing circled less-than relation symbol]

I couldn't find any matching symbol using [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can make the circle match the `\oplus` one by suitable scaling.

The symbol to be circled has to be scaled depending on its size, so `\ogeneric` provides for an optional argument (default `0.7` that seems good for `<`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ogeneric}[2][0.7]{%
  \vphantom{\oplus}\mathpalette\o@generic{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\o@generic}[2]{\o@@generic#1#2}
\newcommand{\o@@generic}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\oplus$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax
  \savebox\tw@[\totalheight]{$\m@th#1\bigcirc$}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{%
    \ooalign{%
      $#1\vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{\dimen@}{!}{\usebox\tw@}}}$\cr
      \hidewidth
      $#1\vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{#2\dimen@}{!}{$#1\vphantom{\oplus}{#3}$}}}$%
      \hidewidth
      \cr
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ole}{\mathrel{\ogeneric{<}}}
\newcommand{\oleq}{\mathrel{\ogeneric[0.6]{\leq}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c\cdot x + y &\leq z\\
c\odot x\oplus y &\oleq z \\
c\odot x\oplus y &\ole z \\
\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\oplus$}\llap{$\ole$}
$\oplus$\llap{\textcolor{red}{$\ole$}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `color` is just for the last line where `\ole` is superimposed to `\oplus` in order to see they match.

The defined symbols can be used also in subscripts and superscripts and they scale properly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is beautiful. By the way, in my opinion, the slanted version of `\leq`, namely `\leqslant` (suggested by Bernard) looks nicer.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add parameters to your `\ogeneric` command to control the horizontal and vertical placement of the inner symbol with respect to the circle, so I can easily add new circled symbols? For instance, when I try to add a circled `=` symbol with `\newcommand{\oeq}{\mathrel{\ogeneric{=}}}`, the `=` turns out off center on the vertical axis.

Comment: @EvanAad Try now, I fixed the code adding a phantom.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly do this in many ways, one of them is Ti*k*Z. Loading Ti*k*Z only for that may be a bit of an overkill, but if you want to construct more symbols of this sort, this might be one of the easiest ways to go.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
c\cdot x + y &\leq z\\
c\odot x\oplus y &\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[circle,draw,inner
sep=1pt](X){$\leq$};} z
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think to achieve best aesthetics, the circle should be the same size as the ones about the arithmetic operators, which means the inequality symbol needs to be shrunk a little. How can I achieve this? Also, how can I make this symbol behave like a binary relation in terms of the spaces surrounding it?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question in your last comment, here is an easy way with `pstricks`. However I'm not sure scaling will look so nice, as the circled symbols won't be aligned with the other symbols. Anyway, I show in the following code some possible variants:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
c\cdot x + y &\leq z\\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leq}} z \\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leqslant}} z \\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leqslant\mkern2mu}} z
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
c\cdot x + y &\leq z\\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\psscalebox{0.67}{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leq}}} z \\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\psscalebox{0.67}{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leqslant}}} z \\
c\odot x\oplus y &\mathrel{\psscalebox{0.67}{\pscirclebox[framesep=-0.7pt, linewidth=0.4pt]{\leqslant\mkern2mu}}} z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, if I wish to have a `\geq` variant of the last version, what do I need to do besides changing `\leqslant` to `\geqslant` so that it looks as well positioned inside the circle as the `\leq` version?

Comment: I don't think you'll have to change whatever else. Just incase, what makes the circle look more centred is adding some math kerning after the symbol (`\mkern2mu`),  which ensures the symbol looks slightly longer tha it is and thus moves the centre of the circle slightly rightwards. You can play with the value of  this kerning if necessary.

Comment: One more question, please. What is `auto-pst-pdf` for? The reason I'm asking is that, for some reason, my TeX editor (Emacs) opens a different viewer than usual when I compile your example, and I think the reason is this package.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to switch the accepted answer to egreg's because his solution scales, is very easy to modify (e.g. add a `\geq` variant), and (this is not your fault, but it still annoys me) my TeX editor opens the same viewer as usual.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry – you accept the answer which is the most useful to you.